# Swift Firebase Auth Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

I'm currently working on an application with integrated Firebase login. 
The last one I developed worked fine but the current App is causing a problem.

I'm taking the input from the Email and Password field and trying to login.

```
func login(user: String, pass: String){
   Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pass) { (user, error) in
   if(error != nil){ 
      print("Success")
   }
}
```

Every time I hit the "Login" button it prints "Success", even when I've not even entered Username and Password (blank text fields)

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhmD.png)

Thanks for your Help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (error != nil) ? Ok try to change if error == nil , because (error != nil) means that there is an error :).

```
func login(user: String, pass: String){
   Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pass) { (user, error) in
   if(error == nil){ 
      print("Success")
   } else {
      print("error")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works now!